# Can't have a function as a class attribute in Python

Tags: class, python-2.x

I want to have a plain old function as a class constant. However, Python "helpfully" turns it into a method for me:

```
class C(object):
    a = 17
    b = (lambda x : x+1)

print C.a     # Works fine for int attributes
print C.b     # Uh-oh... is a <unbound method C.<lambda>> now
print C.b(1)  # TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called
              #    with C instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

- Is there a way to prevent my function from becoming a method?
- In any case, what is the best "Pythonic" approach to this problem?

Comment: Note, the above code works fine in Python 3, where the concept of unbound methods is gone: https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/whatsnew/ . `C.b` is simply a `function`, usable as such in the usual manner.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

staticmethod:

```
class C(object):
    a = 17

    @staticmethod
    def b(x):
      return x+1
```

Or:

```
class C(object):
    a = 17
    b = staticmethod(lambda x : x+1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `staticmethod`:

```
class C(object):
    a = 17
    @staticmethod
    def b(x):
        return x + 1
```

Comment: But you should consider [these caveats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212071/python-class-design-staticmethod-vs-method/5212190#5212190).

Answer (score 4):

Define your function in a module but not class. It's better in your case.

First paramter of normal python method is `self`, `self` must be an instance object.

you should use staticmethod:

```
class C(object):
    a = 17
    b = staticmethod(lambda x: x+1)
print C.b(1)
# output: 2
```

or add `self` parameter, and make an instance of C:

```
class C(object):
    a = 17
    b = lambda self, x: x+1
c = C()
c.b(1)
# output: 2
```

another choice is using classmethod (just show you can do this):

```
class C(object):
    a = 17
    b = classmethod(lambda cls, x: x+1)
C.b(1)
# output: 2
```

Comment: Interesting - lambdas need to be wrapped in staticmethod/classmethod too. I wasn't aware of this before.