# Store and use function as class attribute

Tags: python-3.x, class, lambda

I have made a class which has a function as one of its attributes. The function is created based on parameters `a`,`b`, then stored in the class.

A `write_derivatives` method of the class takes the function and differentiates with `sympy` - it then spits out another lambda function.

However I can't seem to store the functions in the class.

```
class rosenbrock:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.f_ros = lambda x0,x1:(a-x0)**2+b*(x1-x0**2)**2
        self._write_derivatives()

    def _write_derivatives(self):
        self.df_ros_dx0 = partial_diff(self.f_ros(x0,x1),x0) #creates another lambda function
        self.df_ros_dx1 = partial_diff(self.f_ros(x0,x1),x1)
        self.d2f_ros_dx0x0 = partial_diff(self.df_ros_dx0(x0,x1),x0)
        #etc.
```

Taking `self.f_ros` as an example; if I try to save it as I have written here, then I get an error when I call it in `_write_derivatives`

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'

Wrapping it in `staticMethod` [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5999575/6609896) allows me to save it, but then I can't use it without another error

> 'staticmethod' object is not callable

But then unwrapping it with `__func__` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921291/6609896) leads back to the first error

```
self.df_ros_dx0 = partial_diff(self.f_ros.__func__(x0,x1),x0)
```

How can I re-jig my class so that I can store all these functions and use them within the class?